# import Array via MaxScript to keyframes

Tags: maxscript

I have a large dataset:

```
1479661:-1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00;-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00;-1,3,-1,117,-1397,0.00;-1,4,-1,-4,-2420,0.00;4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00;-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00;4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00;:117,-1397,7,7.00,A,Dead;:
```

There are 29 objects in the array separated by ; each object contains a xyz. I have 29 objects in maxfile how do i assign the xyz to each object and record a keyframe then move to the next keyframe in 3ds max and record the next data set (xyz) for the 29 objects:

```
1479662:-1,1,-1,-898,-769,0.00;-1,2,-1,-96,-1402,0.00;-1,3,-1,117,-1392,0.00;-1,4,-1,-6,-2419,0.00;4,5,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,6,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,7,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,8,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,9,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,10,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,11,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,12,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,13,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,14,-1,5570,4395,0.00;-1,15,-1,913,-3533,0.00;4,16,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,17,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,18,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,19,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,20,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,21,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,22,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,23,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,24,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,25,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,26,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,27,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,28,-1,5570,4395,0.00;4,29,-1,5570,4395,0.00;:117,-1392,7,7.07,A,Dead;:
```

The data is stored in a *.dat file at 25 frames per second

Aim is to get the whole data mainly xyz corodinates to each object and record the position to a keyframe

Comment: So what have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I've understood right your file format, but something like this:

```
stream = openFile "file.dat"
data = readLine stream
objs = filterString data ";" --split text for separate lines, each per object
objData = objs[1]
for objData in objs do --for all objects
(
    data = filterString objData ":" --split line for object into name and coords
    obj = getnodebyname data[1] --select object by name
    coords = filterString data[2] "," --get all coords as plain array x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 ...
    keysCount = coords.count / 3 --compute keys count
    with animate on
    (
        for i = 0 to keysCount-1 do --for all keys
        (
            at time i obj.pos.controller.x_position = coords[i*3 + 1] as float
            at time i obj.pos.controller.y_position = coords[i*3 + 2] as float
            at time i obj.pos.controller.z_position = coords[i*3 + 3] as float --read and set position
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks i am trying to test the code and i am getting the error pos IN undefined?

Comment: Do you mean that object is selected correctly (and is stored in variable obj), but calling .pos causes the error?

Comment: Yes, I have selected the object called Box001 and when I run the script it says pos in undefined.

Comment: Can you select the object and run command $.pos in the maxscript listener? If the problem is still there, it means that object doesn't have animation controller PRS (position/rotation/scale). In this case you can still control the position of the object by obj.transform - can you also check, if $.transform in listener gives the result? It would also be much easier to understand the problem, if you attached a screenshot of the scene with opened maxscript window and full text of the error.

Comment: $.transform worked when i ran that in the listener i got the matrix3. also $.pos also worked.

Comment: http://s31.postimg.org/d94wjjfq3/stackoverflow.png - here is a screenshot of the error

Comment: Well, you have "obj: undefined". So object can not be detected. You say you have 29 objects. How you distinguish them in the .dat file? I thought the part before : is the name of the object, so I first select the object by line obj = getnodebyname data[1]